# How can I configure RadASM to work with NASM under Windows7?

Tags: debugging, assembly, windows-7, nasm

I am learning NASM in Linux. Linux doesn't have a convenient **debugger**. **`gdb`** is very difficult and time consuming to use. That is why I wanted an IDE for assembly programming. Looks like RadASM has a good IDE for debugging. But, I am unable to set it up to work it along with NASM.

How can I configure RadASM for NASM?

Note: I have a Win7 64 bit professional edition.

Note-2: If anyone knows any other IDE for debugging NASM, let me know.

Comment: There's WinDbg (from Microsoft), OllyDbg, Watcom Debugger and probably many more. Did you try any of them?

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze, I couldn't configure OllyDbg with RadASM.

Comment: And why do you mention both Linux and Windows? Which OS do you want this for?

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze, I want to do (C, asm) hybrid program with NASM. In Windows.

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze, So far I have tried Cygwin, SASASM IDE. Both fails in int 80h syscalls.

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze, Linux is working very well. But, I can't debug with clumsy gdb. Its very slow and time consuming.

Comment: If you want asm-source-level capable IDE, your options may be few nowadays. However, if you embrace breakpoints, it may be OK even if the debugger shows you just the disassembly. Note, you can put breakpoints into your code, there's `int3` instruction for that.

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze: `gdbgui` (https://github.com/cs01/gdbgui/) works moderately well with NASM / YASM source.  It has a register window, and IIRC setting breakpoints works well enough.  It's a browser-based front-end for GDB.  (I usually just use text GDB with `layout reg`.  It's ugly but I know how to use it, and can set up `display $xmm0.v4_float` or whatever to get a sort of equivalent to a register window for a few vector regs in the right format.)